# Removing / Disabling Wordpress date and /blog links

Tags: php, html, wordpress

**Solution:**

The problem was actually SEO Yoast. It creates "Archives" for posts and authors, creating a whole load of crap on the website.

---

The current template for our wordpress website originally was html only.
A guy we hired some time ago, did the transfer so to speak, but there are some problems.

At the moment the website contains "www.website.com/blog" and various "www.website.com/2018 or /2018/06" links that google does it's damnedest to index. Some of the links return a 404 occasionally as well.

Because we do daily blog post's everything is naturally copied over to those "/blog" pages. The results is 52% duplicate content (according to Siteliner)

I'm writing here looking for advice, because I don't know how to get rid of them or how to manage them to reduce the SEO related impact. I also didn't find post relating to this specific problem.
(example of the problem "multiorders.com/2018/07/page/2/" )

Our post links are set to website.com/sample-post, someone had suggested adding a "RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)$ http://yourwebsite.com/$3" into the .htaccess file.

Comment: Duplicate text is just that. If it's found via crawler, you'll get an error. Without seeing your site or a ten thousand word expansion on what exactly is going on, I don't think anyone would be able to tell you one way or another how to fix your issue. Honestly, I think you need to hire someone to do it right. Feel free to message me if you'd like me to take a look and give you a quote. I've been developing WP sites since 2012, currently manage 4 WP+WooCommerce sites, 4 Magento sites, and 9 WordPress standard sites. carldougelder@gmail.com

Comment: The problem was actually SEO Yoast. It creates "Archives" for posts and authors, creating a whole load of crap on the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually SEO Yoast. It creates "Archives" for posts and authors, creating a whole load of crap on the website. As soon as I disabled those features all the extra pages vanished. Now all I need is to wait for Google to catch up.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you the basic structure to avoid the **Duplicate** content issue and the **URL structure** issue. Both are really important and can say main factor for **Seo purposes**.

**Structure:**
First one, Create a blog page (Already created on your website). On that page there must be shown the all blog posts that you have entered in the admin panel at **POSTS** menu. The lists of all blogs www.example.com/blog here as you said. In that page there should me pagination that means if you are showing 10 posts per page then the 11th post will be on the www.example.com/blog/2 and so on. (acceptable foe seo purpose).

Secondly, If someone clicks on the post or Read more button it should redirect the
single blog  www.example.com/blog-post-name (perfect for seo).

To change the permalink (URL Structure) you have go to the admin settings menu -- permalink menu-- change to post name and Save.

**Note: Take a backup before applying**

Any questions, please ask..!!